# Two-way Java chat using socket

Tags: java, sockets

I tried to find something similar to help me with my code and I also tried to do it by myself but I got stuck on the end and I would really appreciate if someone would help me with that.

So I have already working simple Java Client/Server code and what i want to do is to upgrade it so it can work both ways, right now after launching the server and connecting to it by the client everything what u write as a client will be shown on the server too and i want to upgrade it so what i write on the client will be shown on the server and what i write on the server will be shown on the client.

myServer.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class myServer {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
           int i=0;
           ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9000);
           System.out.println("Listening...");
           Socket s = ss.accept();
           System.out.println("Connection accepted");
           InputStream d1 = s.getInputStream();


            while ((char)i !='q')
        {    
            i = d1.read();
            System.out.print((char)i);

        }
           s.close();
           ss.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("Error"); } 

    }
}
```

myClient.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class myClient {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        int i=0;
        Socket s=new Socket("localhost",9000);
        OutputStream o = s.getOutputStream();


        while ((char)i !='q')
        {
            i = System.in.read();
            o.write((char)i);

        }
        s.close();      
    } catch(Exception e) {System.out.println("Error"); }



    }
}
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Easiest way to start is by multithreading, use one thread for input and one thread for output (socket). This way you can read and write concurrently from the socket and dont have to wait.

Comment: There is plentyful of resources available regarding this topic. Check out for example http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/ Also stackoverflow provides good answers already like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724159/java-simple-server-client-console-chat-application

Comment: I did read this stuff but as I said before I am stuck on this one and I can't fix it, I managed before to upgrade the script a little bit that it work both ways but not exactly how it should and with delay, I know i should add some exception or if statement that the script knows when to check which one is writing and which one is reading (and when to), also I am not sure if I really need multithreading in this one? I just want ONE SERVER that works also as a client communicating with ONE CLIENT, simple script I don't need more advanced one or more clients.